# login into a site, ImportError:cannot import name GopherError

Tags: python

I am trying to login into a site using the `mechanize` module. My script is:

```
import mechanize
from mechanize import Browser

def main():
    try:
        br = mechanize.Browser()
        br.open("site name")
        print br.title()

    except:
        print "error"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Every time I run it I get `ImportError: cannot import name GopherError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 11, in <module>
    import mechanize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\__init__.py", line 85, in <modul
e>
    from _mechanize import __version__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 14, in <mod
ule>
    from _useragent import UserAgentBase
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_useragent.py", line 17, in <mod
ule>
    import _urllib2
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2.py", line 3, in <module
>
    from urllib2 import \
ImportError: cannot import name GopherError
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: paste your full traceback.

Comment: https://www.opencsw.org/mantis/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=4686 ?

Comment: @karthikr , the link has same trace i got but still can't find solution ??

Comment: Did you read the responses below ?

Comment: @karthikr installing CSWpy-mechanize ??

Comment: Yeah.. I was refering to that.

Comment: @karthikr I guess it wont help me , i am in windows

Comment: Error resolved, use new version of mechanize module